# What should I know about developing for 64 bit applications?

Tags: c#

I am planning on getting a 64 bit os so I can see all 4 gigs of memory I have installed.

This raises a question: As a developer, what do I need to know when designing apps for 64 bit OS's? I read somewhere that data types such as int (I code in C#) can hold larger vales (probably due to bytes/bits etc).

Is there anywhere which explains how all this works (a little rusty on my fundamentals and maths I guess)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You won't see much difference in C#. The range of System.IntPtr will change; that's about it. All other numeric types will retain their same range; however operations with Int64 will be more efficient than they would be on 32-bit systems.

When calling unmanaged code, be careful that the unmanaged code is built for 64-bit, and doesn't do 64-bit unsafe things such as casting pointers to ints.

Comment: I agree.  For most C# projects, you can just switch the build configuration to "x64" and you're done.  The thing I've had the most trouble with is third-party libraries, especially ones implemented with unmanaged code.  If you try to use a 32-bit DLL from 64-bit C# (or vice versa) you will get a BadImageFormatException, which can be quite confusing at first.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of helpful information from [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064.aspx).

One of my disappointments in moving to a screamin' 64-bit box was that Visual Studio 2008 only runs as 32-bit.